# Optimizing Data Extraction Speed from Multiple Sheets in Different Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using the following code to extract specific data from two sheets within separate workbooks. However, this process is exceptionally sluggish with almost 2M rows and 5 columns in both sheets.

I'm confident that there's room for improvement, particularly in the search operation, which seems to be the major bottleneck.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or suggestions to optimize the speed and efficiency of this process. Thank you for your valuable help in advance.

```
Sub HFMEMBER_ID()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = FALSE
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
    Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    
    Dim wb1         As Workbook        ' Workbook1
    Dim wb2         As Workbook        ' Workbook2
    Dim wsHF        As Worksheet
    Dim wsWellcare  As Worksheet
    Dim searchValue As Variant
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim sourceRowData As Variant
    Dim targetRow   As Long
    
    ' Set the source workbook (Workbook1)
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("Merged Data.xlsx")        ' Change the filename if needed
    
    ' Set the target workbook (Workbook2 - where the macro is)
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Set the source and target worksheets
    Set wsHF = wb2.Worksheets("HF")        ' Change "HF" to the name of your source worksheet
    Set wsWellcare = wb2.Worksheets("MEMBER_ID")        ' Change "Wellcare" to the name of your target worksheet
    
    Dim lastRow2    As Long
    lastRow2 = wsWellcare.Cells(wsWellcare.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow2 > 1 Then
        wsWellcare.Range("A2:A" & lastRow2).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    
    ' Get the last used row in column C of wsHF
    lastRow = wsHF.Cells(wsHF.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim wsSource1   As Worksheet
    Dim wsSource2   As Worksheet
    ' Set the source worksheets
    Set wsSource1 = wb1.Worksheets("HF1")
    Set wsSource2 = wb1.Worksheets("HF2")
    
    ' Loop through each row in column C of wsHF
    For targetRow = 2 To lastRow
        searchValue = wsHF.Cells(targetRow, "C").Value
        
        ' Skip empty cells
        If searchValue = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Search within the first source worksheet (HF1)
        SearchAndCopy3 wsSource1, searchValue, wsWellcare
        
        ' Search within the second source worksheet (HF2)
        SearchAndCopy3 wsSource2, searchValue, wsWellcare
    Next targetRow
    
    ' ... (rest of the code remains the same)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = TRUE
    Application.DisplayAlerts = TRUE
End Sub

Sub SearchAndCopy3(sourceSheet As Worksheet, searchValue As Variant, targetSheet As Worksheet)
    Dim foundCell   As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim sourceRowData As Variant
    Dim targetRow   As Long
    
    ' Find the first instance of the search value in Column C of the current source worksheet
    Set foundCell = sourceSheet.Columns("C:C").Find(What:=searchValue, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
    ' Check if the value was found at least once
    Do While Not foundCell Is Nothing
        ' If the search value is found, copy the entire row data to the target worksheet (Wellcare)
        sourceRowData = foundCell.EntireRow.Value
        targetRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        ' Copy the entire row data to the target worksheet (Wellcare)
        targetSheet.Cells(targetRow, 1).Resize(1, UBound(sourceRowData, 2)).Value = sourceRowData
        
        ' Find the next instance of the search value in Column C of the current source worksheet
        Set foundCell = sourceSheet.Columns("C:C").FindNext(foundCell)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code work ? The [FindNext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) will never exit as it wraps around to the beginning of the range. Use a compare with the first found address to exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Find()` in a loop (even when coded correctly) is relatively slow, particularly if you're running it repeatedly as a nested loop.

If you're looking for an exact match then using `Match()` or just looping over an array of the range values are both much faster (about 20x in the example below).

Demo:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Range, addr As String, t, rngFind As Range
    Dim fStart As Range, fEnd As Range, m, n As Long, lookForThis As String
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    'set up some dummy data
    With ws.Range("A1:A500000")
        .Formula = "=""Val_"" & TEXT(ROUND(RAND()*100,0),""000"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    Set rngFind = ws.Range("A1:A100000") 'range to be searched
    lookForThis = "Val_050"              'for example
    
    '1. typical "find in a loop" approach
    t = Timer
    n = 0
    Set f = rngFind.Find(lookForThis, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address()
    Do Until f Is Nothing
        'do something with f
        n = n + 1
        If n <= 5 Then Debug.Print f.Address
        Set f = rngFind.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do
    Loop
    Debug.Print "(FIND) Found " & n & " in " & Timer - t
    
    '2. using application.match() in a loop
    t = Timer
    n = 0
    Set f = rngFind.Cells(1)                       'search from here
    Set fEnd = rngFind.Cells(rngFind.Cells.Count)  '...to here
    Do
        m = Application.Match(lookForThis, ws.Range(f, fEnd), 0)
        If IsError(m) Then Exit Do                       'no match
        n = n + 1
        Set f = ws.Range(f, fEnd).Cells(m).Offset(1)     'reset the start of the seach range to the next cell
        If n <= 5 Then Debug.Print f.Offset(-1).Address  'this is the found cell
    Loop
    Debug.Print "(MATCH) Found " & n & " in " & Timer - t

    '3. using array and loop
    t = Timer
    n = 0
    arr = rngFind.Value
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(r, 1) = lookForThis Then
            n = n + 1
            If n <= 5 Then Debug.Print rngFind.Cells(r).Address
        End If
    Next r
    Debug.Print "(ARRAY) Found " & n & " in " & Timer - t
    
End Sub
```

output:

```txt
$A$36
$A$177
$A$211
$A$241
$A$271
(FIND) Found 1043 in 0.5742188
$A$36
$A$177
$A$211
$A$241
$A$271
(MATCH) Found 1043 in 2.734375E-02
$A$36
$A$177
$A$211
$A$241
$A$271
(ARRAY) Found 1043 in 0.03125
```